# Why does the water hang from the ceiling in an underground cave?

Tags: plot-explanation, power-rangers-2017

In Power Rangers (2017), a gang of 5 people falls into water. Billy continues to swim forward & tell the remaining 4 people to swim with him. Suddenly they fall from water surface, which is **hanging** in the air in an underground cave.

[image: 1]]

I know of gravity, why it is not acting here?

Comment: Stop.Creating.New.Accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never explained. Probably just a cool effect added as creative direction. But I could take a few stabs in the dark and say that there is some sort os magnetic force acting because of the ship and all. I could also say its a colateral effect of the morphing grid. Something on that matter.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but you reference a ship, I'm going to assume it's a spaceship? Then it might be related to the spaceship's gravity generators. As gravity is generally spherical, and ships are not, that means there is a bit of area outside of the ship that's still affected by the grav generators.